# Consider the quadratic form $q $ and $p$ given by

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Problem**:Consider the quadratic form $q $ and $p$ given by
>
> $q(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+bw^2$
>
> $p(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+czw$
>
> Which of the following is true $?$
>
> $1)p,q$ are equivalent over $\Bbb C$ if $b$ and $c$ are non zero complex numbers
>
> $2)p,q $ are equivalent over $\Bbb R$ if $b$ and $c$ are non zero real numbers
>
> $3)p,q $ are equivalent over $\Bbb R$ if $b$ and $c$ are non zero real numbers with $b$ negative
>
> $4)p,q $ are not equivalent over $\Bbb R$ if  $c=0$
>
> **Solution**: $q(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+z^2+bw^2$
>
> It will give us diagonal matrix
>
> $$
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>         0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & b \\
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> $p(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+czw$
>
> $p(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2+0z^2+0xy+0xz+0xw+0yz+0yw+czw$
>
> $$
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>         0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{c}{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & \frac{c}{2}& 0 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Am I doing right $?$

Comment: so far, for $p,$ the (3,3) position in the matrix needs to be zero as well.

Comment: @WillJagy,thanks,now it is edited

Comment: Can someone explain whether options in the question are true/false

Answer (score 1):

You can use the invariants of the matrix representations of each quadratic form to determine which of 2-4 is true. The invariants are rank, index and signature - so the number of positive entries and number of negative entries in any diagonal matrix congruent to a matrix remain the same (sylvesters law of inertia for matrices), and from this it can be proved two real symmetric matrices are congruent iff they have the same invariants. So now the question is: can you choose values of b and c (limited according to the prescriptions in each of 2-4) such that the matrix representations of p and q have different invariants - if you can manage to find only 1 such an example for 2-3 then you will have a counter example. 4 you can clearly see is true.

For 1 just observe that every complex symmetric matrix of rank $r$ is congruent to $\begin{bmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: A q is diagonal matrix ,so its eigen values are 1,1,1 and b

Comment: rank $4$,index $4$ and signature $4$(if b is positive non zero) rank $4$,index $3$ and signature $2$(if b is negative non zero)  Eigen values of p are 1,1,c/2,-c/2,\so rank $4$,index $3$ and signature $2$

Comment: clearly option (3),(4) are true and option (2)is false. Is there any method for option (1)

Comment: ok - i edited the answer - you should be able to get (1) now too...

Comment: This means,every complex symmetric matrix of same rank are congruent